# Optimizing multiple SQL inserts by binding parameters using SQL ODBC API

Tags: mysql, odbc

I would like to make multiple row inserts where each individual cell to be added is bound to a variable, using the function [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-ver16). My temptative query is

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ...
```

where the `?` are parameter markers, basically placeholders for the values of the corresponding bound variables. This works fine until I reach the limit number of parameter markers, which is around 32000 (since the number has to fit in two bytes). For large number of rows I then have to execute the query in multiple chunks and this slows down quite a lot. Is there a way to optimize the binding or something else?

My code is basically like this:

```
ret = SQLPrepare(stmt, "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), ...", SQL_NTS);

for (j = 0; j < nchunk; j++ {
  for (i = 1; i <= nparam; i++) {
    ret = SQLBindParameter(stmt, i, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, ...);
  }
  ret = SQLExecute(stmt);
}
```

I have tried with the query

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

where each `?` is bound to the whole column. However, this happens to be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a practical limit to the number of rows you can add in a single INSERT statement.

If you've ever looked at the output of mysqldump, you'll see that it combines multiple rows in each INSERT, but it does do it in batches. It can't insert millions of rows in a single INSERT.

Limitations like `max_allowed_packet` and `net_buffer_length` are responsible for this. A single SQL statement, even with parameter placeholders, must fit within both of those finite buffer sizes.

So you could write code to build your INSERT statement, but give it a cap of how many rows it can add before you execute and then start the next INSERT statement.

If you want to bulk-load many rows in the most efficient manner, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Any tweaking of INSERT syntax is far less effective at bulk-loading than that.

You might like my presentation on this topic, [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. Is there a way to do the same in SQL Server? Also, in your presentation you talk about transactions, do you know how to implement them in ODBC API?

Comment: I don't use SQL Server, but I suppose it has some bulk-loading facility. It only required a few seconds to do a web search for "bulk loading in Microsoft SQL Server" and one of the first matches was this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Likewise, ODBC has documentation. You should read it. It's a lot more efficient use of your time and others' time if you read basic information from existing documentation, and only ask questions on Stack Overflow for things that are not easy to find.